# Alignment issue in the angular component (CSS issue)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have no experience in JS and Angular. And I'm learning it right now. I tried many different variants but I haven't gotten a good solution. I need to get a checkbox component to be alway aligned on the left side and to be visible no matter how big the text is. It works when I use style="width:300px" but it looks like hard coded solution.

[image]

```
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Available Permissions</div>
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            <md-content style="height: 400px;">
                <section>
                    <div class="md-primary md-subheader" style="position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 2;">
                        <div class="md-subheader-inner">
                            <div class="md-subheader-content">
                                <md-input-container class="md-block">
                                    <label for="availableSearchTerm">Search</label>

                                    <input type="text"
                                               name="availableSearchTerm"
                                               id="availableSearchTerm"
                                               data-ng-model="availableSearchTerm"
                                               data-ng-change="searchPermissions(availableSearchTerm, availablePermissions)"/>
                                </md-input-container>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-list class="no-padding" role="list">
                        <md-list-item class="md-3-line md-no-proxy" role="listitem" data-ng-repeat="permission in searchPermissions(availableSearchTerm, availablePermissions)">
                            <md-checkbox aria-label="Permission Chekbox" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" data-ng-click="selectPermission(permission)"/>
                            <div class="md-list-item-text">
                                <h3>{{permission.name}}</h3>
                                <h4>{{permission.description}}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                    </md-list>
                </section>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 text-center" style="padding-top: 180px;">
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="assignPermissions()" class="md-raised btn-w-xs md-default md-button md-ink-ripple" uib-tooltip="Assign Permissions" tooltip-append-to-body="true">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"/>
    </button>
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="removePermissions()" class="md-raised btn-w-xs md-default md-button md-ink-ripple" uib-tooltip="Remove Permissions" tooltip-append-to-body="true" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"/>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Assigned Permissions</div>
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            <md-content style="height: 400px;">
                <section>
                    <div class="md-primary md-subheader" style="position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 2;">
                        <div class="md-subheader-inner">
                            <div class="md-subheader-content">
                                <md-input-container class="md-block">
                                    <label for="assignedSearchTerm">Search</label>

                                    <input type="text"
                                           name="assignedSearchTerm"
                                           id="assignedSearchTerm"
                                           data-ng-model="assignedSearchTerm"
                                           data-ng-change="searchPermissions(assignedSearchTerm, user.permissions)" />
                                </md-input-container>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <md-list class="no-padding" role="list">
                        <md-list-item class="md-3-line md-no-proxy" role="listitem" data-ng-repeat="permission in searchPermissions(assignedSearchTerm, user.permissions)">
                            <md-checkbox aria-label="Permission Chekbox" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" data-ng-click="selectPermission(permission)"/>
                            <div class="md-list-item-text">
                                <h3>{{permission.name}}</h3>
                                <h4>{{permission.description}}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </md-list-item>
                    </md-list>
                </section>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be using CSS, and styling thing like that in a CSS file.  Truly, this is a CSS question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but could you add more details please with a quick example.

Comment: Hi - that was a comment, not an answer.  What my intent was to get you to refocus your question.  For example: Do you know / work with CSS? If so, great! Does your Angular project have a CSS file included in it? If so, great! (If not, that's the first step).  Then, if you do know CSS, and you have a CSS file being included, it would be possible to _answer_ the question.  But these are pre-requisites to being able to actually answer the question well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will wrap long texts.

```
  .md-list-item-text h3,
  .md-list-item-text h4{
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```